# KeyError making pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, modin

I am trying to make find the equation of a function using pandas dataframe. This has worked in the past on other projects, however, now nothing seems to work.

I am aware that there might be easier ways to solve this, but i need this to work somehow.

```
additional_cols = ['xVerdier','fDer']
fdata = pd.DataFrame({"idx":findex,"x":xVerdier[:-1],"y":fDer})
                    

print(fdata)
fdata = fdata.reindex(fdata.columns.tolist() + additional_cols, axis = 1)
fdata=fdata [[xVerdier[:-1],fDer]]
fdata = mpd.DataFrame(fdata)

train=fdata[:(int((len(fdata))))]
test=fdata[(int((len(fdata)))):]

regr=linear_model.LinearRegression()

train_x=np.array(train[[xVerdier]])
train_y=np.array(train[[fDer]])

regr.fit(train_x,train_y)
```

xVerdier is a list of x-values of a graph

```
[0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.30000000000000004, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7999999999999999, 0.8999999999999999, 0.9999999999999999, 1.0999999999999999, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4000000000000001, 1.5000000000000002, 1.6000000000000003, 1.7000000000000004, 1.8000000000000005, 1.9000000000000006, 2.0000000000000004, 2.1000000000000005, 2.2000000000000006, 2.3000000000000007, 2.400000000000001, 2.500000000000001, 2.600000000000001, 2.700000000000001, 2.800000000000001, 2.9000000000000012, 3.0000000000000013, 3.1000000000000014, 3.2000000000000015, 3.3000000000000016, 3.4000000000000017, 3.5000000000000018, 3.600000000000002, 3.700000000000002, 3.800000000000002, 3.900000000000002, 4.000000000000002, 4.100000000000001, 4.200000000000001, 4.300000000000001, 4.4, 4.5, 4.6, 4.699999999999999, 4.799999999999999, 4.899999999999999, 4.999999999999998]
```

fDer is a list of y-values of said graph

```
[1.2, 1.6000000000000003, 2.0000000000000004, 2.4, 2.799999999999999, 3.1999999999999984, 3.5999999999999988, 3.999999999999999, 4.3999999999999995, 4.8, 5.2, 5.600000000000005, 6.000000000000005, 6.400000000000006, 6.800000000000006, 7.200000000000006, 7.600000000000007, 7.999999999999998, 8.400000000000016, 8.79999999999999, 9.200000000000017, 9.600000000000009, 10.000000000000018, 10.40000000000001, 10.800000000000018, 11.20000000000001, 11.600000000000001, 12.000000000000028, 12.40000000000002, 12.799999999999976, 13.200000000000038, 13.60000000000003, 14.000000000000021, 14.400000000000013, 14.80000000000004, 15.199999999999996, 15.600000000000023, 16.00000000000005, 16.400000000000006, 16.799999999999926, 17.19999999999999, 17.59999999999991, 17.99999999999997, 18.399999999999892, 18.799999999999955, 19.199999999999946, 19.599999999999866, 19.99999999999993, 20.39999999999999, 20.799999999999912]
```

This is the error message

```
KeyError: "None of [Index([(0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.30000000000000004, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7999999999999999, 0.8999999999999999, 0.9999999999999999, 1.0999999999999999, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4000000000000001, 1.5000000000000002, 1.6000000000000003, 1.7000000000000004, 1.8000000000000005, 1.9000000000000006, 2.0000000000000004, 2.1000000000000005, 2.2000000000000006, 2.3000000000000007, 2.400000000000001, 2.500000000000001, 2.600000000000001, 2.700000000000001, 2.800000000000001, 2.9000000000000012, 3.0000000000000013, 3.1000000000000014, 3.2000000000000015, 3.3000000000000016, 3.4000000000000017, 3.5000000000000018, 3.600000000000002, 3.700000000000002, 3.800000000000002, 3.900000000000002, 4.000000000000002, 4.100000000000001, 4.200000000000001, 4.300000000000001, 4.4, 4.5, 4.6, 4.699999999999999, 4.799999999999999, 4.899999999999999), (1.2, 1.6000000000000003, 2.0000000000000004, 2.4, 2.799999999999999, 3.1999999999999984, 3.5999999999999988, 3.999999999999999, 4.3999999999999995, 4.8, 5.2, 5.600000000000005, 6.000000000000005, 6.400000000000006, 6.800000000000006, 7.200000000000006, 7.600000000000007, 7.999999999999998, 8.400000000000016, 8.79999999999999, 9.200000000000017, 9.600000000000009, 10.000000000000018, 10.40000000000001, 10.800000000000018, 11.20000000000001, 11.600000000000001, 12.000000000000028, 12.40000000000002, 12.799999999999976, 13.200000000000038, 13.60000000000003, 14.000000000000021, 14.400000000000013, 14.80000000000004, 15.199999999999996, 15.600000000000023, 16.00000000000005, 16.400000000000006, 16.799999999999926, 17.19999999999999, 17.59999999999991, 17.99999999999997, 18.399999999999892, 18.799999999999955, 19.199999999999946, 19.599999999999866, 19.99999999999993, 20.39999999999999, 20.799999999999912)], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

Comment: Maybe you want to slice on the index instead of the columns, and also unpack the data in `xVerdier[:1]` and `fDer`, instead of using those long tuples. Maybe this works: `fdata=fdata.loc[[*xVerdier[:1], *fDer]]`

Comment: I still get the same error. I believe the problem occurs when i first define fdata.

Comment: If you show us what xVerdier  and fDer look like, we can help more. From what you showed here, xVerdier could be a list or a pd.Series (of course could be something else that supports slicing). If it is a list, you simply need to set and index for the dataframe, if it is a series (and fDer is also a series), it shouldn't break

Comment: @gionni
i did `fdata.set_index(findex)` and I now have another error message
`KeyError: 'None of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50] are in the columns'`

findex is a list of numbers from 1 to 50

Comment: `set_index()` accepts either a column name or a list of the same length of your dataframe. In your case `fdata.set_index("idx")` does what you are trying to do, although it will not fix your original slicing problem. I could help you more if I knew what you were trying to accomplish.

Comment: @gionni I am trying to use the dataframe to find the equation of a graph using sklearn. I've added a bit more to the original post to show this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.